# pycuda -- how to deal with 'including libraries'

Tags: pycuda

I have a code in c++.I modified it with cuda.But ,i want to use Pycuda.
The code has for example :

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <complex>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

typedef std::complex<double> cmplx;
typedef std::vector< boost::array<std::complex<double>,3 > > ComplexFieldType;
typedef std::vector< boost::array<double,3> > RealFieldType;
```

In Pycuda you can't use the libraries.
How can i deal with that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be interested check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857063/cuda-pycuda-how-to-write-complex-numbers-errorsclass-cucomplex-has-no)

You can use `#include <pycuda-complex.hpp>`