# cuda, pycuda -- how to write complex numbers -- errors:class "cuComplex" has no member "i"

Tags: c++, cuda, complex-numbers, pycuda

I have difficulties to use complex numbers in cuda,pycuda.

I have this in C:

```
#include <complex>
typedef std::complex<double> cmplx;
....
cmplx j(0.,1.);
```

Also,in the same code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
...
typedef std::vector< boost::array<std::complex<double>,3 > > ComplexFieldType;
typedef std::vector< boost::array<double,3> > RealFieldType;
...
__global__ void compute(RealFieldType const & Rs,ComplexFieldType const & M,..)
...
```

How can i convert this to use it with pycuda?
I tried sth like this (according to the book 'cuda by an example'):

```
struct cuComplex {
    float real;
    float imag;
    cuComplex(float a,float b): real(a),imag(b){} 
    cuComplex operator *(const cuComplex& a) {
    return cuComplex(real*a.real -imag*a.imag ,imag*a.real +real*a.imag);
    }
cuComplex operator +(const cuComplex& a) {
    return cuComplex(real+a.real ,imag+a.imag);
    };  

cuComplex j(0.,1.);    //instead of  cmplx j(0.,1.);  

 __global__ void compute(float *Rs,cuComplex * M,..)  //instead of RealFieldType const & Rs,ComplexFieldType const & M
....
```

Some of the errors i take are:

> data member initializer is not allowed
>
> this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Thank you!

--------------------**-EDIT-**---------------------------------------------

I did the following using `#include <pycuda-complex.hpp>`  (relative to the above) :

```
pycuda::complex<float> cmplx;

cmplx j(0.,1.);
```

and as for `typedef std::vector< boost::array<std::complex<double>,3 > > ComplexFieldType;`

and `ComplexFieldType const & M` ,inside the global function,
i tried  just "float *M " or "cmplx *M".

Until now , i am getting error :

> variable "cmplx" is not a type name

If i use  pycuda::complex cmplx; ,then i get:

> identifier "cmplx" is undefined
>
> name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name

Also:

> > expression must have pointer-to-object type (but maybe this is from another part of code)

Comment: According to structure definition, it has `real` and `imag` fields instead of `i` and `r`. Also note that they are `float`, not `double` as in your C code.

Comment: Ok, thanks!I updated now!I don't think (maybe i am wrong) having them as float in the cuda code is wrong.(I tried it also with double but still the same errors).

Comment: @George: the error "variable "cmplx" is not a type name" should tell you everything you need to fix the problem. If it doesn't, you need to revise some basic C++ - this is an extremely elementary and self explanatory mistake.

Comment: @talonmies:I try "typedef pycuda::complex<float> cmplx;" but it gives me "no operator "*" matches these operands operand types are: cmplx * double".If i try "typedef typeof pycuda::complex<float> cmplx;" it gives me "type name is not allowed" .I don't have such an experience in c ,so i don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really isn't clear what you are actually trying to do (if you actually know yourself), and the question is getting progressively more confused as the edits and comments roll on. But to expand Andreas's answer a little, here is a simple, compilable piece of CUDA code which uses the pycuda native complex type correctly:

```
#include <pycuda-complex.hpp>

template<typename T>
__global__ void kernel(const T * x, const T *y, T *z)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    z[tid] = x[tid] + y[tid];
}


typedef pycuda::complex<float> scmplx;
typedef pycuda::complex<double> dcmplx;

template void kernel<float>(const float *, const float *, float *);
template void kernel<double>(const double *, const double *, double *);
template void kernel<scmplx>(const scmplx *, const scmplx *, scmplx *);
template void kernel<dcmplx>(const dcmplx *, const dcmplx *, dcmplx *);
```

This gives you single and double real and complex versions of the trivial kernel and compiles with nvcc something like this:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -Xptxas="-v" -I$HOME/pycuda-2011.1.2/src/cuda -c scmplx.cu 
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelIN6pycuda7complexIdEEEvPKT_S5_PS3_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Used 12 registers, 44 bytes cmem[0], 168 bytes cmem[2], 4 bytes cmem[16]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelIN6pycuda7complexIfEEEvPKT_S5_PS3_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Used 8 registers, 44 bytes cmem[0], 168 bytes cmem[2]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelIdEvPKT_S2_PS0_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Used 8 registers, 44 bytes cmem[0], 168 bytes cmem[2]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelIfEvPKT_S2_PS0_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Used 4 registers, 44 bytes cmem[0], 168 bytes cmem[2]
```

Perhaps this goes someway to answering your question....

Comment: I am using typedef pycuda::complex<float> cmplx; but it gives me "no operator "*" matches these operands operand types are: cmplx * double" because i have some calculations as "Cn2 = Cn1*3.0 - 2.0;" ,where Cn2 and Cn1 are cmplx. Thanks!(i vote up)

Comment: The error message is telling you that you are mixing single and double precision types. `3.0` is a double precision constant. `3.0f`is a single precision constant. Seriously, you would be best served by taking the time to learn some basic C++ before you continue with this, because it is painfully obvious you are not going to get very far as it is.

Comment: :First of all thanks!That was the problem for this.Second,i've never encounter such problems before and as i said i don't have much experience in C++.Sure,i need a LOT of exercising!But you see,the projects are running!:).Anyway , i also get the error " expression must have pointer-to-object type" ,do you have sth in mind?Thanks!

Comment: Ok,this has to do with pointers and arrays.I figured that i had an array as float.Changed to float * and its ok.Now,i must search where is the other mistake.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
#include <pycuda-complex.hpp>

{
  pycuda::complex<float> x(5, 17);
}
```

Same interface as `std::complex<>`, in fact derived from the STLport version of that.

Comment: :Hello Andreas,can you check my post again?I did as you said but still have problems.I updated.Thanks!